# Two distinct public IP addresses keeping dynamic DNS and port forwarding from working?

Tags: port-forwarding, dynamic-dns

I use dynamic DNS to point my domain to my home IP address and then, in the ISP modem, I forward ports 80 and 443 to my home web server. However, I'm apparently dealing with two distinct public IP addresses and the process is not working (I can't access my home server from the internet).

The status page of the ISP modem informs the public IP address is `100.64.xxx.xxx`, but my dynamic DNS provider's dashboard (as well as other URLs like `myip.dnsomatic.com` and `icanhazip.com`) detects it as being `170.79.xxx.xxx`.

When I ping my domain from a Linux machine, I get the following result:

> ```
> PING mydomain.com (100.64.xxx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
> 64 bytes from xxx-xxx-79-170.myisp.net.br (100.64.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.05 ms
> ```

Notice the resulting ISP URL (`xxx-xxx-79-170.myisp.net.br`) contains the detected public IP address (`170.79.xxx.xxx`), only inverted.

Can I correct this issue with some type of DNS record, or isn't this even related to DNS at all? As you might have guessed by now, I'm not exactly a specialist on the matter.

Comment: What are the first two octets of what your modem tells you?

Comment: @RonMaupin The address informed by the modem (1.2.3.4) is 100.64.X.X, while the one detected by online tools (5.6.7.8) is 170.79.X.X.

Comment: The `100.64.0.0/10` address space is _not_ public address space. It is Shared Address space for ISPs to run NAT.

Comment: You should either accept an existing answer, or provide and accept your own answer, otherwise the question will keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: It's rather nonstandard here for question to contain an answer, even as an "update". **We tend to separate questions and answers.** I would post this update as a comment to the accepted answer or as a separate answer (aside the accepted one). I'm not saying the things are bad now as they are; I'm saying *in my opinion* they would be better the other way. I haven't edited your update out though, it's up to you to reconsider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your ISP is using CGN (Carrier-Grade NAT). Some ISPs do this with Private Addressing  ([*RFC 1918, Address Allocation for Private Internets*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)), and some use the Shared Address Space (`100.64.0.0/10` per [*RFC 6598, IANA-Reserved IPv4 Prefix for Shared Address Space*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598)) set aside for this, which is what your ISP is using.

That means that the port forwarding must happen on the ISP NAT, over which you have no control. The ISP really doesn't care that you cannot forward ports to your home servers because there is a clause in your residential ISP agreement that prohibits you from running servers to the public Internet. There is not much you can do about this, but you could try asking your ISP about it.

Comment: I'll call them and ask, then. Is there any technical restriction, or does it depend entirely on the good will of the ISP? Thank you again for such a quick response.

Comment: Your ISP, like many ISPs, has basically run out of IPv4 addresses because the RIRs have run out of IPv4 addresses to assign to the ISPs. The ISPs are now using CGN for residential customers in order to save their precious public IPv4 addresses for business customers willing to pay for them.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely aCarrier Grade NAT issue - because the Modem IP address is in the CGN range.   You have 2 practical options - change to a provider/plan which does not use CGN or set up a VPN from your home system to provider that will give you a static IP.

Comment: If the ISP offered static public IP addresses, would it solve the issue? I hope they won't charge too much for it.

Comment: Yes.  (it would.)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

As it was explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/1262480/791849) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/1262487/791849) the issue was, indeed, about the use of Carrier Grade NAT (a.k.a. Large Scale NAT) by the ISP. After calling them and telling we needed external access to the home server, they changed it so that now the modem gets a public IP address. Thank God for that (I was afraid I'd have to pay for a dedicated IP address or resort to VPN/SSH tunneling)!

Thanks for all the answers.